# mysql getting maximum match in like operation

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i am executing a sql query which doesn't gives me required output:

Table:

```
  -----------------------   
  |  col1                |
  ----------------------   
  |  data for hello user |
  |   data               |
   -----------------------
```

sql query `Select * from table where col1 like'%data%' or col1 like '%for%' or col1 like '%hello%' ;`

it shows me out put:

```
  -----------------------   
  |  col1                |
  ----------------------   
  |  data                |
  |  data for hello user |
   -----------------------
```

but  as `data for hello user` has maximun match with sql like operation so `data for hello user` comes first and `data` second

Please help me

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using full text search for this.

Comment: do you have any key columns in your table?

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in internet for fulltext search of mysql.
You can obtain what you are searching for.

Example

```
CREATE TABLE tableName ( 
      tablekey INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      col1 VARCHAR(200), 
      FULLTEXT (col1) 
);


SELECT col1, MATCH(col1) AGAINST('data for help') AS accuracy
FROM table 
WHERE MATCH(col1) AGAINST('data for help') 
ORDER BY accuracy DESC
```

Will return something like

```
-------------------------------------
|  col1                |  accuracy  |
-------------------------------------
|  data for hello user |    70      |
|  data                |    10      |
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: +1 for showing the correct way of doing it.

Comment: error #1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Comment: @user3808438 Fulltest search index is supported only for MYISAM or InnoDB tables

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963534/mysql-fulltext-indexes-issue

Comment: i used
      `ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; `
  
There is no problem table has been created but when executing query:

    `SELECT col1, MATCH(col1) AGAINST('data for help') AS accuracy FROM table WHERE MATCH(col1) AGAINST('data for help') ORDER BY accuracy DESC`

output:
 

    `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0007 sec)`

Comment: @user3808438 try removing the where "WHERE MATCH(col1) AGAINST('data for help')". Now you should see the type of data returned by "accuracy"... After that you can set something like "WHERE MATCH(col1) AGAINST('data for help') HAVING accuracy> 0.2"

Comment: i want to know that is this not working for non-dictionary words

Comment: `SELECT col1, MATCH(col1) AGAINST('data for help') AS accuracy FROM tablename ORDER BY accuracy DESC;` Output  `accuracy=0 accuracy=0`

Comment: also for data `SELECT col1, MATCH(col1) AGAINST('data') AS accuracy FROM tablename ORDER BY accuracy DESC;` Output  `accuracy=0 accuracy=0`

Comment: @user3808438 table contains data? :D