# how to search a specific keyword from mysql database

Tags: mysql

here my table looks like

```
course{
id,title,description,instructor}
```

i was trying to match a word from description

this is what i have tried

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ('java' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

got this error
    Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Comment: `MATCH .. AGAINST` can be applied only when you have created fulltext index previously. Do it. Or use common searching via string functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL FULLTEXT indexes issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963534/mysql-fulltext-indexes-issue)

Comment: i have not created the fulltext index   thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use this:

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE description LIKE '%java%'
```